# Send message using XMPP openfire in swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, xmpp, openfire, sendmessage

I want to send message using xmpp to openFire everything works perfect even i can receive message. but not able to send i don't know why? i tried this code:

```
@IBAction func SendMessageClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

       let message = messageTextField.text
        var clientJid: XMPPJID!
        clientJid = XMPPJID.init(string: "Bure@ip-772-99-99-99.ec3.internal")
        let senderJID = clientJid
          let msg = XMPPMessage(type: "chat", to: senderJID)
        msg?.addBody(message)
        stream?.send(msg)
}
```

As it doesnot throw any error but message does not send.
Plese help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let xMessage = XMPPMessage(type: "chat", to: XMPPJID(string: clientJid))
        xMessage.addBody(message)
        xMessage.addOriginId(stream.generateUUID)
        stream.send(xMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just found the issue. Make sure the connection is established and authentication is done completely before trying to send messages. To do that you can use these `XMPPStreamDelegate` functions:

```
func xmppStreamDidConnect(_ stream: XMPPStream!) {
    //Connection is now established
}

func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
    //Athentication is done. Now you can send messages.
}
```